# Error message is different when deployed on website and when deployed in R

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny, flexdashboard

I would like the error message that is displayed in R to be displayed in my app so that users can know when something went wrong.  This is the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hLeY.png)
that is produced after I press "Run Document" to test my Shiny App on my computer. It is produced by a package that I am using to run a simulation.

I then deployed the shiny app to shipyapps.io and ran the same analysis.  However, I now get this [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhPTc.png)
: "An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification."

Does anyone know why the error message would show up correctly in my app when tested on my computer, but not when I deploy my app on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `options(shiny.sanitize.errors = FALSE)` to my code and the error message began deploying as expected.  This is supposed to be the default but was not for me, for some reason.